# Low average variance extracted (AVE) for a construct that measures self-reported behavior

Tags: variance, latent-variable, path-model

I want to use a latent variable as a dependent variable in a path analysis. The indicators of the   variable are self-reported behaviors like donate to an environmental NGO, recycle, and use public transport.  After I perform confirmatory factor analysis,   I find that the average variance extracted (AVE) for   the variable is less than the recommended threshold of .5. My questions are:
When self-reported behavior is measured, few behaviors are easier than others, and frequency of these behaviors varies among participants. So, in case of latent variables that are attempting to measure self-reported behavior, can we use a lower value of AVE as a threshold for assessing   the convergent validity of our measurement model?  Is there any reference that gives guidelines of what to do to deal with the low AVE? I  should add that the value of alpha reliability and   composite reliability are  above the commonly recommended threshold of .70.

Answer (score 1):

If AVE is less than 0.5,but composite reliability is higher than 0.6, the convergent
validity of the construct can be adequate (Fornell & Larcker, 1981)